# An error occurred while attempting to read the boot configuration data

Tags: windows-7, hard-drive, usb-flash-drive, windows-installation, bootable-media

I have the Windows 7 installation media on a USB drive.  I get the error "An error occurred while attempting to read the boot configuration data" when I boot to it on an older computer.  The drive works on other computers.  I saw a posting saying that this problem can occur if the drive is not formatted as FAT32, but my drive is FAT32.

Answer (score 0):

- Format the USB flash drive in FAT32
- Download and use UltraISO software
- Open your ISO file in UltraISO software
- Extract Windows 7 ISO file into USB flash drive

Windows 7 Bootable ISO Download

[Windows 7 Ultimate (x86)* - 32 bit](http://msft.digitalrivercontent.net/win/X17-59463.iso)

[Windows 7 Ultimate (x64)* - 64 bit](http://msft.digitalrivercontent.net/win/X17-59465.iso)

Comment: It would be useful to include more information in your answer on how to perform these operations.